# Eclipse RCP: Switching perspectives with progress dialog

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

We have an Eclipse RCP application that has a few perspectives (so called 'features'). Switching between these features may take a few seconds, that's why I want to show the user a progress dialog

```
final Job jobMain = new Job("Opening feature ...") {

    @Override
    protected IStatus run(final IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        monitor.beginTask("Opening ...", 100);
        monitor.worked(50);
        while (!monitor.isCanceled()) {
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        monitor.worked(50);
        monitor.done();

        return Status.OK_STATUS;
    }

};

Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        jobMain.setUser(true);
        jobMain.setProgressGroup(Job.getJobManager().createProgressGroup(), 100);
        jobMain.schedule();
    }
});
thread.start();
try {
    thread.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
}

Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ftSelectedFeature.openFeaturePerspective();
        jobMain.cancel();
    }
});
```

I have tried everything and the above "solution" is as close it could get to what I want. The problem is, the progress dialog only shows **after** the feature perspective has opened (*ftSelectedFeature.openFeaturePerspective()*).

How do I get a progress dialog to show while the feature perspective is switching?

Comment: Why is the perspective load so slow? It sounds like you should be moving code in the load in to Jobs so that the perspective load is fast with the Jobs running after to finish the job.

Comment: There is some heavy work going on in the background that might also be done when the application starts, but as not all features are used all the times the application is used it would be a waste of time on startup I reckon.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you do the work on startup. I am suggesting you schedule Jobs to do the work when required and display the UI before the Jobs have completed. You should not be running heavy code in the UI thread as it will make the UI unresponsive.